# horizontally centering td in html email using inline stlyes

Tags: html, outlook, html-table, inline, centering

I am writing an html email using inline styles since I'll be sending it in Outlook and read that's the best way to circumvent browser reformatting.  I want to center the two links below, which I put into table cells because that's the only way I could get padding to work in Outlook.  I would like the 2 links to appear centered with their background and padding on the page, but I don't know how to do that using inline styling and tables.  Can anyone help?  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>email blast re films</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px; font-size: 14px; background: #3D87F5; color: white;">
            <a href="http://bartonlewisfilm.com/artwork/4258558-wall-cuts-train-stations-New-York-City-excerpt.html" style="padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px; background: #3D87F5; text-decoration: none; color: white; border-radius: 5px;" title="watch wall cuts, train stations, New York City" target="_blank;">Watch my film "wall cuts, train stations, New York City"</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px; font-size: 14px; background: #3D87F5; color: white;">
            <a href="http://http://bartonlewisfilm.com/artwork/4264539-red-hook-rush-hour-excerpt.html" style="padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px; background: #3D87F5; text-decoration: none; color: white; border-radius: 5px;" title="watch red hook, rush hour" target="_blank;">Watch my film "red hook, rush hour"</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 14px; text-align: center; padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px; background: #3A8E47;">
            <a href="http://www.bartonlewisfilm.com" style="display: inline-block; padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px; background:  #3A8E47; 
    text-decoration: none; color: white;" title="visit bartonlewisfilm.com" target="_blank;">bartonlewisfilm.com</a> | home &#40;718&#41; 399-8344 | cell &#40;347&#41; 325-4415
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you want to center the content of the cell, you can add style in the td{ } text-align:center;  and vertical-align:middle;

Comment: that centers the text inside the td, but i want to center the td on the page.

Comment: then put the table inside a div and position the div absolute

Comment: or make the table height and width 100%; same as td, see my answer i updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of using `padding` on each cell, you can just specify `cellpadding` attribute for a `table` tag -

```
<table cellpadding="10">
```

The cell content is centered by default -

```
<table cellpadding="10">
   <tr>
      <td style="background-color: red;">
          <a href="address">Link 1</a><br/>
          <a href="address">Link 2</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td style="background-color: red;">
          <a href="address">Link 1</a><br/>
          <a href="address">Link 2</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

UPD

To center the whole table, set `margin` to `0 auto` -

```
<table style="margin: 0 auto;">
```

To center only either a row or a column, apply accordingly -

```
<tr style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; display: table;"></tr>
or 
<td style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; display: table;"></td>
```

Comment: that did work in place of padding in each td.  now if i could just get the cells centered (not just the text inside them).  i added the footer to show how it runs longer than the 2 cells above - what i want is them centered above the footer.  thanks if you have any suggestions.

Comment: You can center the whole table by setting up margin to auto, like `<table style="margin: auto;"></table>`

Comment: If you do not want to center the whole table, you can center either only `<tr>` or `<td>` - on the element, just set `style="width: 50%; margin: 0 auto; display: table"`

Comment: When I tried this (50% width; margin 0 auto; display table) the code appears correctly in Live Preview of my code editor but in Outlook using Bells & Whistles to insert html the td is twice as big as the line of text as shown by the bckgd color; so td's are different sizes.  I put a max-width of 500px in each of the 2 table tags but it's like the cells are ignoring that and stretching to be twice as big as text inside. Text is centered inside cell but the cells are different sizes.  Is this an Outlook problem are my code?  I assume it's Outlook since it looks okay in the Live Preview.  Thanks.

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using? Apparently Outlook 2007/10/13 does not support such tags as `display` and `max-width`. You can find a list of supported tags here - https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ So, will need to change those to get it working.

Comment: ok thanks.  do you happen to know what the white "i" in the blue circle means at that table of supported tags that you provided the link to?  that's a big help.  i guess i really should find some other way to send the html email than outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You add an align attribute to the td cell.

```
<td align="center" style="padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px; font-size: 14px; background: #3D87F5; color: white;"> <a href="www.somesite.com">Your link </a>
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding margin to body tag, will that work for you.

```
 <body style="margin-top:20%;margin-bottom:20%;margin-left:30%;">
```

Comment: no, i want the table cells floating in the middle of the page, above the footer that i added to the html so you can see how it's longer than the cells - and so they should be horizontally centered above the footer.  adding margins to the body affects the entire container, with the td's inside of it moving but not in relation to the body, but with the body.

Answer (score 0):

Use text-align:center, vertical-align:middle,

```css
table{width:100%;height:100%;}
td{width:100%;height:100%; text-align:center; vertical-align:middle; font-size: 14px; }
a, a:link, a:visited{padding:10px; display:inline-block; color: white; text-decoration: none;margin:10px; background: #3D87F5; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>email blast re films</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <div id="centerme">
                <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="http://bartonlewisfilm.com/artwork/4258558-wall-cuts-train-stations-New-York-City-excerpt.html" title="watch wall cuts, train stations, New York City" target="_blank;">Watch my film "wall cuts, train stations, New York City"</a>
                <br/>
                    <a href="http://http://bartonlewisfilm.com/artwork/4264539-red-hook-rush-hour-excerpt.html"  title="watch red hook, rush hour" target="_blank;">Watch my film "red hook, rush hour"</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this html. Appears fine to me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>email blast re films</title>
    </head>
    <body style="height:height:500px;">
        <table border="0" style="width:100%; text-align:center;">
    <tr>
        <td >
            <span style="border-radius: 5px;display:block;margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%;margin-top:10%;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px; font-size: 14px; background: #3D87F5; color: white;"><a href="http://bartonlewisfilm.com/artwork/4258558-wall-cuts-train-stations-New-York-City-excerpt.html" style="padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px; background: #3D87F5; text-decoration: none; color: white; " title="watch wall cuts, train stations, New York City" target="_blank;">Watch my film "wall cuts, train stations, New York City"</a></span>
            <span style="display:block;margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px; font-size: 14px; color: white;border-radius:5px;">&nbsp;</span>

            <span style="border-radius: 5px;display:block;margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px; font-size: 14px; background: #3D87F5; color: white;"><a href="http://http://bartonlewisfilm.com/artwork/4264539-red-hook-rush-hour-excerpt.html" style="padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px; background: #3D87F5; text-decoration: none; color: white; border-radius: 5px;" title="watch red hook, rush hour" target="_blank;">Watch my film "red hook, rush hour"</a></span>
            <span style="display:block;margin-left:20%;margin-right:20%;padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px; font-size: 14px; color: white;border-radius:5px;">&nbsp;</span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td style="font-size: 14px; text-align: center; padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px; background: #3A8E47;">
            <a href="http://www.bartonlewisfilm.com" style="display: inline-block; padding-top:10px;padding-right:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px; background:  #3A8E47; 
    text-decoration: none; color: white;" title="visit bartonlewisfilm.com" target="_blank;">bartonlewisfilm.com</a> | home &#40;718&#41; 399-8344 | cell &#40;347&#41; 325-4415
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```